# Eclipse Java Project Compilation Error Using Ivy

Tags: eclipse, caching, ivy

My Java project uses Ivy.xml in Eclipse. After I update some code, I have to manually delete ivy cache, or restart the Eclipse and resolve the ivy.xml. Otherwise, Eclipse does not recognize some objects, and throws compilation errors. Does anybody know the reason? Is there any method to avoid manually clearing the ivy cache?

Comment: do you use the workspace resolver of the ivyde plugin?

Comment: Yes, I do. And I use ant to build the project. I found that those compilation errors threw out after building. Then, I need to click resolve twice from ivyde plugin. Those errors disappeared.

Comment: maybe try the "resolve all" button instead of deleting the cache. sometimes eclipse and ivyde have trouble working together.

Comment: My ivyde has no "resolve all" button, only "Resolve" button. I use Eclipse J2EE version.